# How do you get the general solution?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I get all the steps in the following solution except for the final step to the get the general solution:

also how can I write the maths more clearly in the description?

$a_n = 7a_{n-1} + (-30) \cdot 2^n$

substitute $a_n=c \cdot 2^n$

$c \cdot2^n=7c \cdot2^{n-1} + (-30)\cdot2^n$

$2c=7c-30\cdot2$

$c={30 \cdot 2\over5} = 12$

general solution: $a_n=c \cdot 7^n+12\cdot2^n$

Comment: I've put your first line in "$"s to make it a MathJax rendered equation.  You might adapt that to your other equation lines.  For more on MathJax markup, see the [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You have $7a_n-1$.  Do you mean $7a_{n-1}$?

Comment: yh, I have updated this

Answer (score 2):

This is an *inhomogeneous linear problem*. The general solution of such a problem can be described as follows:

1. Find the general solution of the associated homogeneous problem
   $$a_n=7 a_{n-1}\ .$$
   In our simple example this general solution can easily be guessed as $$a_{\rm hom}(n)=C\cdot 7^n\qquad(n\geq0)\ .$$
2. Find a single solution of the given inhomogeneous problem, using the inhomogeneity as a hint. This you have done, and have found the so-called *particular solution*
   $$a_{\rm part}(n)=12\cdot 2^n\qquad(n\geq0)\ .$$
3. The general solution of the given problem then can be written as
   $$a_n=a_{\rm hom}(n)+a_{\rm part}(n)=C\cdot 7^n+12\cdot 2^n\qquad(n\geq0)\ ,$$
   with $C$ an arbitrary real constant. (This $C$ has nothing to do with the $c$ you used in 2.)